# Named Pipes, How to know the exact number of bytes to read on Reading side. C++, Windows

Tags: c++, named-pipes

I am using Named Pipes configured to send data as a single byte stream to send serialized data structures between two applications. The serialized data changes in size quite dramatically. On the sending side, this is not a problem, I can adjust the number of bytes to send exactly.

How can I set the buffer on the receiveing (Reading) end to the exact number of bytes to read? Is there a way to know how big the data is on the sending (Writing) side is?

I have looked at PeekNamedPipe, but the function appears useless for byte typed named pipes?

> lpBytesLeftThisMessage [out, optional]
>   A pointer to a variable that receives the number of bytes remaining in this message. This parameter will be zero for byte-type named pipes or for anonymous pipes. This parameter can be NULL if no data is to be read.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365779(v=vs.85).aspx

How does one handle such a situation best if you cannot determine the exact required buffer size?

Sending Code

```
    string strData;
strData =  "ShortLittleString";

DWORD numBytesWritten = 0;
result = WriteFile(
    pipe, // handle to our outbound pipe
    strData.c_str(), // data to send
    strData.length(), // length of data to send (bytes)
    &numBytesWritten, // will store actual amount of data sent
    NULL // not using overlapped IO
);
```

Reading Code:

```
DWORD numBytesToRead0 = 0;
DWORD numBytesToRead1 = 0;
DWORD numBytesToRead2 = 0;

BOOL result = PeekNamedPipe(
pipe,
NULL,
42,
&numBytesToRead0,
&numBytesToRead1,
&numBytesToRead2
);

char * buffer ;

buffer = new char[numBytesToRead2];

char data[1024]; //1024 is way too big and numBytesToRead2 is always 0 
DWORD _numBytesRead = 0;

BOOL    result = ReadFile(
pipe,
data, // the data from the pipe will be put here
1024, // number of bytes allocated
&_numBytesRead, // this will store number of bytes actually read
NULL // not using overlapped IO
);
```

In the code above *buffer* is always of size 0 as the PeakNamedPipe function returns 0 for all *numBytesToRead* variables. Is there a way to set this buffer size exactly? If not, what is the best way to handle such a situation? Thanks for any help!

Comment: A simple approach is to write the length first, then the data.  The receiver can then simple read the length first and allocate the buffer.   Not unlike the way pipe message mode works.

Answer (score 7):

Why do you think you could not use `lpTotalBytesAvail` to get sent data size? It always works for me in bytes mode. If it's always zero possibly you did something wrong. Also suggest to use `std::vector` as data buffer, it's quite more safe than messing with raw pointers and `new` statement.

> `lpTotalBytesAvail [out, optional]` A pointer to a variable that receives the total number of bytes available to be read from the pipe. This parameter can be NULL if no data is to be read.

Sample code:

```
// Get data size available from pipe
DWORD bytesAvail = 0;
BOOL isOK = PeekNamedPipe(hPipe, NULL, 0, NULL, &bytesAvail, NULL);
if(!isOK)
{
   // Check GetLastError() code
}

// Allocate buffer and peek data from pipe
DWORD bytesRead = 0;    
std::vector<char> buffer(bytesAvail);
isOK = PeekNamedPipe(hPipe, &buffer[0], bytesAvail, &bytesRead, NULL, NULL);
if(!isOK)
{
   // Check GetLastError() code
}
```

Comment: lpTotalBytesAvail worked great for me!  This saved me a lot of trouble and expensive buffer copies to prepend the size as Hans Passant had suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are using ReadFile(). The documentation says, among other things:

> If a named pipe is being read in message mode and the next message is longer
>   than the nNumberOfBytesToRead parameter specifies, ReadFile returns FALSE and
>   GetLastError returns ERROR_MORE_DATA. The remainder of the message can be read
>   by a subsequent call to the ReadFile or PeekNamedPipefunction.

Did you try that? I've never used a pipe like this :-), only used them to get to the stdin/out handles of a child process.

I'm assuming that the above can be repeated as often as necessary, making the "remainder of the message" a somewhat inaccurate description: I think if the "remainder" doesn't fit into your buffer you'll just get another ERROR_MORE_DATA so you know to get the remainder of the remainder.

Or, if I'm completely misunderstanding you and you're not actually using this "message mode" thing: maybe you are just reading things the wrong way. You could just use a fixed size buffer to read data into and append it to your final block, until you've reached the end of the data. Or optimize this a bit by increasing the size of the "fixed" size buffer as you go along.

Comment: No I haven't. It seems like a bit of a hack, but are you suggesting I read in very small increments and loop until I don't get a ERROR_MORE_DATA error anymore? :) That should work, but I'm trying to avoid appending the data size to the message or ending up with irrelevant data appended to the serialised data - basically any char/string based clean up work after reading the message. Is there no way to read until EOF like reading a text file? Can I insert my own EOF on the Write side maybe?

Comment: I'm not using message mode, I'm using byte mode. :) But I think you just gave me an idea, I think byte mode is meant to be used when sending fixed length chars, I will chop and change the system to a message mode pipe and report back?

Comment: byte mode is specifically designed to put the onus on *you* to manage the messaging protocol, or lack thereof, for the usage case you're implementing. In other words, part of message-pipes is the attribute of message length. no such attribute exists in byte-mode unless *you* manage it by sending data which represents it. put it another way, message mode is a guy handing you  a box that has a label on it saying how much it holds. byte mode is just a guy throwing product at you. unless you know whats on the mind of 'the guy' you don't have enough to really work with.